# Unable to open jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed anaconda and tensorflow library in Ubuntu .Suddenly it stopped working. When i try to open it i am getting this issue.I have already googled it but unable to get the solution. Please help me on this

```
:/tmp$ jupyter notebook
[I 12:41:24.704 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 2 kernels found
[I 12:41:24.712 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/bhavani/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 652, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1071, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 919, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/bhavani/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 194, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: try doing conda run jupyter notebook

Comment: Thank for your response . I tried your solution but it is giving another following issue conda run jupyter notebook
CommandNotFoundError: Command Error: error with command 'run'. Command not found: 'run'. Error: Could not locate 'conda-run' run Error: Could not locate 'conda-run'

Comment: Looks like you have 2 kernels, or two jupyter notebooks installed. Install it through pip and try

Comment: Also run jupyter from terminal as --- jupyter-notebook